# Can I extend the default URI schemes that vscode detects?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Visual Studio Code has the nice feature to automatically render URIs in source to clickable links, as the following examples demonstrate:

```
http://web.org
file:///local.txt
https://archive.org
```

[image: examples of recognized URLs in source]

Is it possible to extend the feature to detect custom URI schemes? We use a certain scheme at work that's proprietary. It would be awesome to make our internal links added to our source clickable to open our internal tools.

To be concrete is there some way to make text like the following in my source clickable?

```
foo://test.resource
```

Comment: Looked around a bit and didn't find anything obvious. You might want to look at either `registerFileSystemProvider(scheme: string, provider: FileSystemProvider, options?: {isCaseSensitive: boolean, isReadonly: boolean}): Disposable` or `registerTextDocumentContentProvider(scheme: string, provider: TextDocumentContentProvider): Disposable` in the extension API to see if you can make those do what you want.